# Unit test class unable to find class in another project in the same solution i want to test

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to perform some basic unit tests on a class that's in one project in a solution (Let's call it Project1) in another unit test project (Let's call it UnitTest1) in c++. I'm using the very latest version of visual studio 2019.

I created a brand new solution in visual studio 2019 for c++, and added a console application with a class HelloWorld in another file that just has a method to return a std::string "Hello World".

I then added a new "Native Unit Test Project" to the solution, under references added the Project1 console application, and typed the code as shown below:

The project1 file:

```cpp
    #include <iostream>
    #include "HelloWorld.h"

    int main() {
    HelloWorld* hello = new HelloWorld();
        std::cout << hello->sayHello();
    }
```

HelloWorld.h:

```cpp
    #pragma once
    #include <string>

    class HelloWorld {
    public: HelloWorld();
    public: std::string sayHello();
    };
```

HelloWorld.cpp:

```cpp
    #include "HelloWorld.h"
    #include <string>

    HelloWorld::HelloWorld() {

    }

    std::string HelloWorld::sayHello() {
    return std::string("Hello World");
    }
```

UnitTest1.cpp:

```cpp
    #include "pch.h"
    #include "CppUnitTest.h"
    #include "..//ConsoleApplication1/HelloWorld.h"

    using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

    namespace UnitTest1 {
    TEST_CLASS(UnitTest1)
    {
    public:

        TEST_METHOD(TestMethod1)
        {
            HelloWorld* hello = new HelloWorld();
            Assert::AreEqual(hello->sayHello(), std::string("Hello World"));
        }
    };
    }
```

When i try to run the test via the test explorer, i get:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: UnitTest1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>pch.cpp
1>UnitTest1.cpp
1>   Creating library C:\Users\Iblob\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\Debug\UnitTest1.lib and object C:\Users\Iblob\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\Debug\UnitTest1.exp
1>UnitTest1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall HelloWorld::HelloWorld(void)" (??0HelloWorld@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall UnitTest1::UnitTest1::TestMethod1(void)" (?TestMethod1@UnitTest1@1@QAEXXZ)
1>UnitTest1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall HelloWorld::sayHello(void)" (?sayHello@HelloWorld@@QAE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall UnitTest1::UnitTest1::TestMethod1(void)" (?TestMethod1@UnitTest1@1@QAEXXZ)
1>C:\Users\Iblob\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\Debug\UnitTest1.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "UnitTest1.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I would have hoped that the linker should be able to find the files referenced according to microsofts own tutorial on this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/writing-unit-tests-for-c-cpp?view=vs-2019

I've tried adding the classes header and cpp as an existing item to my unit test project, but then it just tries to find #include "pch.h" in the HelloWorld class when i try to run the tests.

What am i missing here to tell linker where to find the classes symbols?

Comment: You should add `HelloWorld` project to unit test project dependencies.

Comment: That was already done, i checked just now as well by right clicking UnitTest1 > Build dependencies > project dependencies > Box for the project containing hello world was checked.

Comment: Off-topic, but you created memory leaks, you don't ever `delete` the objects created. Maybe not critical, you're going to exit anyway, but you should get used to foresee the `delete` for every `new` right from the start. Better: use smart pointers instead. Even better: create the objects in local scope (`HelloWorld helloWorld;`). C++ is not Java, you don't need to specify `public` for every single function.

Comment: Off-topic,use Assert.IsTrue(string1.Equals(string2)) to compare "Hello World" in your  unit test since string is a reference type. So when Assert tries to compare string, it compares references and not actual string.

Comment: @KethiriSundar This is c++, direct comparison is fine.

Comment: @Iblob Can you share your solution/project files?

Answer (score 0):

Adding #include "..//ConsoleApplication1/HelloWorld.cpp" to my unitTest1.cpp file seems to have fixed things, although i'm not sure if this is an ideal solution, still, will mark as answer.